Oracle SQL: Trying to join by a 'level' value using connect by ("ORA-00976: Specified pseudocolumn or operator not allowed here")
I am trying to write a query to pull back a time-series of dates, and associated counts of 'open orders' from an already existing open orders view.
I have a view - TMP_ORDERS_VIEW - which produces columns:



ORDER_UID
ORDER_OPEN_DATE
ORDER_CLOSED_DATE




111111111
11-01-2024
18-01-2024


222222222
14-01-2024
20-02-2024


333333333
14-01-2024
14-01-2024


444444444
11-01-2023



...
...
...



This view has ~20,000 rows. Orders which are still open today may be without an order-closed-date, but always have an ID & order open date. I'm only interested in counts for dates between today and 2023-10-01.
Ideal output is:



dt
open_orders_count_on_dt




01-oct-2023
5


02-oct-2023
0


03-oct-2023
11


04-oct-2023
10


...
...


...
...


01-apr-2024
10



In other words: The output I'm hoping for is a series counts (one count per date from 01-oct-2024 -> today) of how many orders were open on that day. (i.e. for dates, n, count orders where ORDER_OPEN_DATE<=n && ORDER_CLOSED_DATE>=n). This query does not need to be fast or especially performant. I want it as a date-series so it's easy to convert into a line-graph.
I've written a query to attempt to do this using 'levels' -- but oracle is giving me the error message:

ORA-00976: Specified pseudocolumn or operator not allowed here.

Whenever I include 'level' in the 'ON'. and I am very unsure how I can tweak this query to work, or if my approach is just completely wrong. I'm not too familiar with 'level' iterative queries overall, so I hope I'm just missing something small - can you see how I can tweak this query to work for my use-case?
select dt + (level - 1), open_orders_count_on_dt
from (select TO_DATE('01-OCT-23', 'dd-MON-YYYY') dt from dual)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        select dt + (level - 1) ofcdt, count(ORDER_UID) open_orders_count_on_dt
        from TMP_ORDERS_VIEW
        where order_created_date<=dt AND NVL(order_closed_date, current_date)>=dt
    ) OFC on (ofcdt = dt + (level - 1))
connect by dt + (level - 1) <= TO_DATE('01-APR-24', 'dd-MON-YYYY');

Solution:
@Jon Waterhouse's solution got me 95% of the way there. The solution that worked in the end was:
with date_range as
  (select DATE'2023-10-01' + (level - 1) tgt_date
  from dual 
  connect by level  <= DATE'2024-04-01' - DATE'2023-10-01'
  )
select r.tgt_date, count(order_id) open_orders_count_on_dt
from TMP_ORDERS_VIEW v
join date_range r on v.created_date<=r.tgt_date 
where NVL(closed_date, current_date)>=r.tgt_date
**group by r.tgt_date**
;

i.e. I had to add a group-by clause and tweak a couple of the column names.
To generalize for future searchers, I think the main things I was doing wrong was:

Trying to explicitly join using the 'level' value (Instead, I should've just stuck one of my where clauses into the 'on') - which is not something i would've thought of

Trying to wrap the entire query with the connect-by - it's clearer to use the 'with' construct instead.



Something like
with date_range as
  (select DATE'2023-10-01' + (level - 1) tgt_date
  from dual 
  connect by level  <= DATE'2024-04-01' - DATE'2023-10-01'
  )
select r.tgt_date, count(ORDER_UID) open_orders_count_on_dt
from TMP_ORDERS_VIEW v
join date_range r on v.order_created_date<=r.tgt_dt 
where NVL(order_closed_date, current_date)>= r.tgt_date

should work for you. I've just used date'isodate' rather than to_date from personal preference. Basically -- create the date range first in the CTE. I, and probably Oracle, find the connect by wrapped around the whole query mind-bogglingly confusing. If you needed to show dates on which there were no still-open orders, you'd need to use date_range as your main table and left join the view.

Yep this got me 95% of the way there. I just added a group-by & tweaked some of the specifics. I also don't need to worry about days with 0 open orders as it turns out there aren't any.
Am I right in thinking - besides structuring it confusingly, the main thing I was doing wrong was trying to explicitly join - instead of just putting one of the 'where' clauses into the 'on' like you do in your example?

You want:

To generate a calendar and then JOIN to the calendar.
to use SYSDATE rather than hard-code today's date.

Like this:
SELECT c.dt,
       COUNT(o.order_uid) AS open_orders_count_on_dt
FROM   (
         SELECT DATE '2023-10-01' + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY DATE '2023-10-01' + LEVEL - 1 <= SYSDATE
       ) c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP_ORDERS_VIEW o
       ON o.order_created_date <= c.dt
          AND (o.order_closed_date IS NULL OR o.order_closed_date >= c.dt)

